# Dockerized ffmpeg stops for no reason

Tags: docker, ffmpeg

I'm trying to fire up a container that reads a video stream via `ffmpeg` and saves the stream as 30 seconds segments.

When I run the container, it stops after 20-ish seconds and returns with no error.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM linuxserver/ffmpeg
ENTRYPOINT ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.1.85:8554/camera -f v4l2 -c copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 30 -segment_format mp4 "output/out%03d.mp4" -loglevel debug
```

Here is the output when I run `sudo docker run -it --rm -v /data/camera:/output --name camera_recorder camera_recorder:latest`

```
[+] Building 1.8s (5/5) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.3s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 777B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.5s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/linuxserver/ffmpeg:latest                                                                                                                                                                                                      1.2s
 => CACHED [1/1] FROM docker.io/linuxserver/ffmpeg@sha256:823c611e0af82b864608c21d96bf363403310d92f154e238f6d51fe3d783e53b                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.1s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:f0509ccf0b07ff53d4aafa0d3b80fd50ed53e96db906c9a1e0e8c44e163dce94                                                                                                                                                                              0.1s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/camera_recorder                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
ffmpeg version 5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
  configuration: --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-ffplay --enable-ffprobe --enable-cuvid --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxml2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-opencl --enable-openssl --enable-small --enable-stripping --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-version3
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'rtsp://192.168.1.85:8554/camera'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'v4l2'.
Reading option '-c' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-reset_timestamps' ... matched as AVOption 'reset_timestamps' with argument '1'.
Reading option '-map' ... matched as option 'map' (set input stream mapping) with argument '0'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'segment'.
Reading option '-segment_time' ... matched as AVOption 'segment_time' with argument '30'.
Reading option '-segment_format' ... matched as AVOption 'segment_format' with argument 'mp4'.
Reading option 'output/out%03d.mp4' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url rtsp://192.168.1.85:8554/camera.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: rtsp://192.168.1.85:8554/camera.
[tcp @ 0x55c15e3eb040] No default whitelist set
[tcp @ 0x55c15e3eb040] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0x55c15e3eb040] Address 192.168.1.85 port 8554
[tcp @ 0x55c15e3eb040] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0x55c15e3eb040] Address 192.168.1.85 port 8554
[tcp @ 0x55c15e3eb040] Starting connection attempt to 192.168.1.85 port 8554
[tcp @ 0x55c15e3eb040] Successfully connected to 192.168.1.85 port 8554
[rtsp @ 0x55c15e3e8300] SDP:
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=Stream
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
t=0 0
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
a=control:rtsp://192.168.1.85:8554/camera/trackID=0
a=rtpmap:96 MP4V-ES/90000
a=fmtp:96 config=000001B001000001B58913000001000000012000C48D88002D3C04871443000001B24C61766335392E33372E313030; profile-level-id=1

[rtsp @ 0x55c15e3e8300] video codec set to: mpeg4
[rtp @ 0x55c15e3ef600] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 0x55c15e3f0200] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 0x55c15e3f0200] end receive buffer size reported is 425984
[udp @ 0x55c15e3eff40] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 0x55c15e3eff40] end receive buffer size reported is 425984
[rtsp @ 0x55c15e3e8300] setting jitter buffer size to 500
[rtsp @ 0x55c15e3e8300] hello state=0
[rtsp @ 0x55c15e3e8300] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mpeg4, 1 reference frame, none(left), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1/5): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://192.168.1.85:8554/camera':
  Metadata:
    title           : Stream
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0, 0, 1/90000: Video: mpeg4, 1 reference frame, none(left), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 0/1, 5 tbr, 90k tbn
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url output/out%03d.mp4.
Applying option f (force format) with argument v4l2.
Applying option c (codec name) with argument copy.
Applying option map (set input stream mapping) with argument 0.
Applying option f (force format) with argument segment.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: output/out%03d.mp4.
Successfully opened the file.
[segment @ 0x55c15e415a80] Selected stream id:0 type:video
[segment @ 0x55c15e415a80] Opening 'output/out000.mp4' for writing
[file @ 0x55c15e42d840] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
Output #0, segment, to 'output/out%03d.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : Stream
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:0, 0, 1/10240: Video: mpeg4, 1 reference frame, none(left), 1920x1080 (0x0) [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 0/1, q=2-31, 5 tbr, 10240 tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
No more output streams to write to, finishing.:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
[segment @ 0x55c15e415a80] segment:'output/out000.mp4' count:0 ended
[AVIOContext @ 0x55c15e42d8c0] Statistics: 292 bytes written, 2 seeks, 3 writeouts
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Input file #0 (rtsp://192.168.1.85:8554/camera):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 0 packets read (0 bytes);
  Total: 0 packets (0 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (output/out%03d.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 0 packets muxed (0 bytes);
  Total: 0 packets (0 bytes) muxed
0 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
```

Additional info :

- The stream is up and running. `ffplay rtsp://192.168.1.85:8554/camera` opens normally
- The exact command (from `ENTRYPOINT`) on the host, works perfectly fine (it generates files for every 30 seconds).
- From inside the container, I can ping 192.168.1.85 (it is actually `localhost`)
- Setting `-analyzeduration 1000` does not fix the issue

Why is the container stopping for no reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the dockerized version of `ffmpeg` could not automatically figure out that the rtsp protocol was using TCP.

While it worked out of the box on most other systems, this particular one needed to have it specified explicitly by adding `-rtsp_transport tcp`

Thus, the final command being

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.1.85:8554/camera -f v4l2 -c copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 30 -segment_format mp4 "output/out%03d.mp4" -analyzeduration 1000
```